# Razor C# fazer lista e sublista com List<String> (originalmente "como verificar se um elemento HTML já existe")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor

Preciso saber se um elemento HTML já existe, no meu loop, se ele existir eu uso ele, se ele não existir eu crio um.

Como faria isso dentro de um

```
@foreach (var item in Model){ ... }
```

Seguindo o comentário do Cigano, como não é possível eu queria uma lógica assim:

- Tenho um `List<String>` ordenado alfabeticamente.
- Todas as strings que começam com `A` eu quero que fiquem abaixo de um `<li>A</li>`

Quero um `<ul>` com os `<li>`s organizados desse forma. Alguém tem alguma dica?

Preciso disso dinâmico porque está sempre mudando os valores.

Comment: O Razor não avalia elementos HTML: apenas elementos dentro do MVC. Creio que é impossível fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Então, como não é possível eu editei a pergunta colocando outra solução possível. Obrigado.

Comment: Melhorou muito. Agora já posso responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estou supondo que `Model` é `List<String>`, logo posso ordenar alfabeticamente e agrupar os valores pela primeira letra de cada `String`:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(s => s).GroupBy(s => s[0])) 
{
    <li>
        @item.Key
        @if (item.ToList().Count > 0) {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var subitem in item.ToList()) 
            {
                <li>@subitem</li>
            }
        </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
</ul>
```